# VSCode PhpStorm formatter fails

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpstorm, formatter

I have installed PhpStorm formatter in VSCode (latest update) and we have PhpStorm installed on the computer I work with. I went to preferences/settings and I set the "Editor:default formatter" to PhpStorm formatter in VSCode.

My VSCode settings.json looks like this:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 2,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Quiet Light",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-simpler-icons",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.background": "#f3f3f3",
        "sideBar.background": "#e9e9e9"
    },
    "workbench.statusBar.visible": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "blade.format.enable": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "animus-coop.vscode-phpstorm-formatter",
    "phpstormFormatter.ideBinPath": "C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PhpStorm 2019.3.2\\bin",
    "editor.fontSize": 15
}
```

But when I push <kbd>Alt+Shift+F</kbd> to format the code in VSCode, an error pops up saying:

> Failed to format this document.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the idebinpath like this, works for me

```
"phpstormFormatter.ideBinPath": "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PhpStorm 2019.2.3/bin",
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to your VSCode `settings.json` this line:

```
"phpstormFormatter.styleGuidePath": "C:\\Path\\to\\your\\configuration\\file.xml"
```

You have to export that `file.xml` from your PHPStorm (like this image) and save it in that path on your PC:

[image: PHPStorm export format]

It worked for me. Regards!